# Finding the common non null columns between an index row and every row in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the percentage of non null columns that are common between an index row and a data frame. For example:

df(index) =

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
3  NaN  4  NaN  5   6
```

and df1 =

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
1   3   5  NaN  7  NaN
NaN 2   4  NaN  3   2
7   6  NaN  5   2  NaN
2  NaN  5  NaN  7   3
```

and I am looking for the percentage of non null common columns. So ideally the result would be:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   Common%
    1   3   5  NaN  7  NaN    75
    NaN 2   4  NaN  3   2     75
    7   6  NaN  5   2  NaN    50
    2  NaN  5  NaN  7   3     100
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the common values mean?

Comment: So for the first row in df1, A B C and E are non null, and in df(index) A C E and F are non null. So A C E are common between the two. So {A, C, E} / {A, C, E, F} = 3/4 which is equal to 75%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do:

```
df['Common%'] = (df == index).sum() / index.shape * 100
```

Note that this will only work if `index` is a `Series`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
  # create mask for non-nan values
v = ~np.isnan(df)
w = ~np.isnan(df1)

# count non zeros of intersection
a = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(w, v), axis=1)

# count non zeros of v (number of non-nan values in df)
b = np.count_nonzero(v)

# find common percentage
print((a / b) * 100)
```

**Output**

```
[ 75.  75.  50. 100.]
```

You can add the new column like this:

```
df1['common'] = (a / b) * 100
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
     A    B    C    D  E    F  common
0  1.0  3.0  5.0  NaN  7  NaN    75.0
1  NaN  2.0  4.0  NaN  3  2.0    75.0
2  7.0  6.0  NaN  5.0  2  NaN    50.0
3  2.0  NaN  5.0  NaN  7  3.0   100.0
```